# Log4j logging not working when rhq-remoting-cli-4.7.0.jar is present in lib folder

Tags: jboss, log4j, rhq

I have web application deployed on JBOSS 5.0.1 GA server and lib folder contains rhq-remoting-cli-4.7.0.jar. Will there be any conflict with Log4j logging?

If I removed rhq-remoting-cli-4.7.0.jar then logging do happens but when this file exists the logging does not happen.

Let me know if any more information is required.

Please advice?